# A long, obscure word with the meaning "abstruse, erudite, (of a text) difficult"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, obscure-terms

I have forgotten a particular word. It's very rare, but not so rare that it doesn't appear in online dictionaries—for instance, it appeared in Google Search's dedicated dictionary widget with its definition when I searched it. It's not a nonce word.

I recall that it was remarkably long and was composed of lots of Latin affixes (e.g *ex-*), and so on (think *polyphiloprogenitive*). It meant "abstruse, erudite, (of a text) difficult, etc."; in short, it described the kind of text in which it might appear. It is not the word *sesquipedalian*.

I am at my wit's end looking for this evasive word, which has eluded me for about a month of on-and-off casual detective work. Any help would be appreciated! The main thing that struck me about the word was its length. It was an adjective. It might be used as:

> The philosopher's essay was a ____ meditation on the concept of being.

Comment: Possibly "obfuscated"?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: Much longer, much more specific, and much, much more obscure than obfuscated. I write an approximation of its meaning (to have an exact dictionary definition of the word ready to hand, I'd need to remember it) in the post: "It meant abstruse, erudite, (of a text) difficult, etc."

Comment: Looks as if he has done some research so keep plugging.

Comment: How could any single term encompass "abstruse, erudite and (of anything) difficult"?

Comment: Did you try thesaurus.com or rogets.com? The original Roget's thesaurus was bit entiriely to answer questions just like this, but I'm not sure if the modern online versions have maintained the depth of the original.

Comment: _Obfuscate_ is clearly the right verb. Check out the [International Obfuscated C Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/) (C is a programming language; obfuscated C programs are incomprehensible to read, but they all compile and run).

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't sesquipedalian...

maybe it's ***hippopotomonstro***sesquipedalian.

definition: pertaining to long words.

https://www.wordsense.eu/hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian/

Comment: It was not this word, but thank you for the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

A long, obscure adjective with a similar meaning; and modelled on a Latin lexical item is ***imperspicuous***. *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/92341#eid854370)* provides the etymology and the definition as below:

> **Etymology:** < im- *prefix*<sup>2</sup> + perspicuous *adj.*, after classical Latin *imperspicuus* not clear, obscure.
>
> Not clearly expressed or easily understood; obscure, opaque; (of a speaker or writer) unclear in style, meaning, or expression.

Comment: I don't believe it was this word, but thank you for the attempt! The definition you have quoted is remarkably close to the definition I recall my word had.

Comment: No problem. This was the closest word I could think of that fits the criteria. Do you have more hints? Was it longer? Do you remember any affixes or how the word starts/ends, or any words that it sounds like etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing I can remember is that it was very likely longer than the word imperspicuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Inenubilable** could fit. There is a whole group of words etymologically related to shadow or clouds that mean obscurity and are themselves somewhat obscure. This one had the most syllables out of what I could find.

OED, [inenubilable](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/94964), adj.:

> *rare*
>
> That cannot be cleared of clouds or mist, or (*figurative*) of obscurity; indistinct; inexplicable

Comment: '... a whole group of words etymologically related to shadow or clouds that mean obscurity and are themselves somewhat obscure' ... happily autologous.